# How do I add a notification within a master detail page that slides from the right when a button is pressed

Tags: xamarin.forms, notifications, code-behind, master-detail

I need to add a notification content that will slide from the right when a button in the header is pressed. The header is a boxview with buttons inside.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have now(button does nothing):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Xamarin.Forms supports two Master pages (Drawers) but what you could do is add a view inside your page with it's `TranslationX` set to the `Width` of the screen, then add a `ToolbarItem` that, when pressed, Translates the `X` of the view to 0, and when pressed again, translates the view to the screen's width again. The only drawback is that this view would be below the AppBar (not like your picture that the notification panel is in front of the AppBar and the StatusBar).

The code would be something like this:

The notifications panel part:

```
// I think 260 is a good width (but I didn't test), experiment and see
var notificationsPanel = new StackLayout { WidthRequest = 260 };

// Needed because we don't know the Width yet
SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(Width > 0)
        notificationsPanel.TranslationX = Width;
}
```

The `Width` property is the Width of the page.

---

The ToolbarItem part:

```
if(notificationsPanel.TranslationX > 0)
    notificationsPanel.TranslateTo(Width - notificationsPanel.Width);
else
    notificationsPanel.TranslateTo(Width); // Here the Width will already be set
```

---

The Content of the Page:

```
Content = new Grid
{
    Children =
    {
        actualContent,
        notificationsPanel
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT**

An easier idea would be to create your page **without** the Notifications Panel and use this library: [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/) to add the NotificationsPanel as a Popup instead of as a view inside the page.

This library has a wiki page here: [Wiki](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/How-to-use). You can create a XAML page for your Popup and add a ToolbarItem on the "Root" page that, when clicked, calls a simple method that checks if a Popup is showing, if it's not, add it, if it is, remove it (a toggle-like method). Something like this:

```
if (PopupNavigation.PopupStack.Count > 0)
    PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
else
    PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new NotificationsPanel());
```

If you don't know how to add a ToolbarItem, it's something like this:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem 
{
    Text = "Notifications",
    Icon = "notifications-icon.png" // change this based on your image requirements, Xamarin.Forms has more than one way to store images
    Command = new Command(() => 
    {
        if (PopupNavigation.PopupStack.Count > 0)
            PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
        else
            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new NotificationsPanel());
    })
});
```

If you want to know more about images with Xamarin.Forms: [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/)

That's it. If you want you can add animations (to make the NotificationsPanel come from the right side of the screen) and in the NotificationsPanel PopupPage, remember to make the view aligned to the right and with a WidthRequest smaller than the screen's Width.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't really understand what I need to do as I am quite new to this. Are all these codes supposed to be put in the .xaml.cs file below the InitializeComponent() method?

Comment: Nope, I just prefer to write C# instead of XAML, I think it's much more simple. To make this work with XAML you would need to create a root layout in XAML (could be a simple Grid) and add your actual XAML as it's contents, then, on the code, add the notificationsLayout to the root view. I can't explain better right now, tomorrow I'll update my answer with a detailed explanation :)

Comment: See my new edit, the end result will be much better and easier to implement.

Comment: Not sure exactly what a toolbar item is or where it goes. Does it appear on the navbar of the content page or as an item in the master detail list?

Comment: The ToolbarItem appears on the NavigationBar of the ContentPage, and it's a property of ContentPage. But @Scar, I have to say that if you don't know what a ToolbarItem is, you are trying to do something too difficult for your current level. I suggest you create other parts of your application (easier parts) and get used to Xamarin.Forms first. And a second suggestion to your programming as a whole: when you don't know something, search for it first, then ask about it if you don't find anything (like the ToolbarItem, that you can find the info on Xamarin's documentation). Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I have already completed other pages of my app and am left with this. I have cosen to use a boxview as the navigation bar and have edited the question. Is there any example on how to overlay the view?